# How to add images in gridview inside the fragment of the navigation bar item

Tags: android, image, gridview, fragment, navigation-drawer

I have been trying to get bunch of images like gallery inside my fragment of the navigation bar item. here the code goes like this.

`public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;`

```
public Integer[] images = {
        R.drawable.base1, R.drawable.base2,
        R.drawable.base3, R.drawable.base2,
        R.drawable.base1, R.drawable.base3,

};

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    context = c;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return images.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return images(position);
}

private Object images(int position) {

    return images(position);
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View ConvertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageview = new ImageView(context);
    imageview.setImageResource(images[position]);
    imageview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageview.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(240, 240));
    return imageview;
}
```

And in the main activity I have set this

`GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);`

```
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));`
```

but whenever i run my app i get this error. Here is the logcat

> 07-20 08:34:49.974 4608-4608/com.example.android.navigation D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>   07-20 08:34:49.975 4608-4608/com.example.android.navigation E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                 Process: com.example.android.navigation, PID: 4608
>                                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.navigation/com.example.android.navigation.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.GridView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.GridView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                     at com.example.android.navigation.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
>                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
>                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Note: Don't get confused with the images R.drawable.base123. I just wrote 3 to make it short. I have set 20 images on my workspace.

Comment: According to stacktrace, your gridview is null. Have you define it?

Comment: If i define gridview in main xml then the images will appear in every other navigation item too. I want different images to be appeared on different item clicked on navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare "gridView"  before the onCreate method

```
private GridView mGridView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.yourLayout);
  mGridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);

 mGridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Check onCreate method of your activity, may be you are referring to the wrong `R.layout` file

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{ 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Check this
        setContentView(R.layout.filters); 
}
```